# Run GitHub workflow on branch being deleted

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have an GitHub workflow that is triggered on branch deletion:

```
on:
  delete:
jobs:
  delete-development-pipeline:
    if: github.event.ref_type == 'branch'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

but it is triggered *after* the branch is deleted, so it checks out the main branch to run action on.

Is there a way to run this action on the branch being deleted?